# flutter how to start listWiew on index 5

Tags: list, flutter, listview

I have a list of 12 items. I hav a LisView like this:

```html
child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: (snapshot.data.length / 2).round(),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Row(
                            children: [
                              Checkbox(
                                  value: false,
                                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                                    _swipeCheckboxState(value, index);
                                  }),
                              Text(snapshot.data[index]['name'].toString()),
                              //Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
```

Now I would like to split my view of the elements into 2 columns. How can I do this in Flutter?

Comment: Create a `Row` with two `ListView` widgets should do it

Comment: How do you mean? If I do that then I will have 2 lists with the same content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a Row with two ListViews inside.

In the second ListView update the itemCount and the index like this:

```
Row(
    children: [
        ListView.builder(
            itemCount: (snapshot.data.length / 2).round(),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Row(
                    children: [
                          Checkbox(
                              value: false,
                              onChanged: (bool value) {
                                _swipeCheckboxState(value, index);
                              }),
                          Text(snapshot.data[index]['name'].toString()),
                          //Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
                    ],
                  );
            },
         ),
        ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length - (snapshot.data.length / 2).round(),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Row(
                    children: [
                       Checkbox(
                           value: false,
                           onChanged: (bool value) {
                             _swipeCheckboxState(value, index + (snapshot.data.length / 2).round());
                           }),
                       Text(snapshot.data[index + (snapshot.data.length / 2).round()]['name'].toString()),
                       //Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
                    ],
                  );
            },
         ),
    ],
),
```